# Smalltalk, take command line argument as filename

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I am new to Smalltalk and am trying to figure out how to take in a command line argument as a filename. I've seen this following snippet online:

```
f := FileStream open: 'fileName' mode: FileStream read
```

But I want to know how to modify that based on a user's command line input for the fileName. The following is how this project would be compiled and ran:

`gst file1.st file2.st file3.st file4.st -f mainFile.st readThisFile.dat addiotnalArg`

So how can I pull the name of the user specified file in Smalltalk?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual/gst.html#Invocation
you can access the command line arguments that are not interpreted by GNU Smalltalk itself with `Smalltalk arguments`. It will be an array that contains those arguments as Strings.

> -a 
>   --smalltalk-args
>
> Treat all options afterward as arguments to be given to Smalltalk code retrievable with `Smalltalk arguments`, ignoring them as arguments to GNU Smalltalk itself.
>   [...]
>
> -f 
>   --file
>
> The following two command lines are equivalent:
>
> ```
> gst -f file args...
> gst -q file -a args...
> ```

Since your readThisFile.dat is the first argument, you can access it with `Smalltalk arguments at: 1` and put that into your FileStream constructor message:

```
f := FileStream open: (Smalltalk arguments at: 1) mode: FileStream read
```

You can also use `first`

```
f := FileStream open: Smalltalk arguments first mode: FileStream read.
```